# How to find out which package was installed from GitHub in my R library?

Tags: r, github, devtools, install.packages

I want to know how many packages in my current library were installed from GitHub but can't find a way to go about it

```
# The number of installed packages in my library
length(.packages(all.available=TRUE))
[1] 145
```

This R-bloggers post showed the versions of the packages but not where they were installed from
https://www.r-bloggers.com/list-of-user-installed-r-packages-and-their-versions/

```
ip <- as.data.frame(installed.packages()[, c(1, 3:4)])
rownames(ip) <- NULL
ip <- ip[is.na(ip$Priority), 1:2, drop=FALSE]
print(ip, row.names=FALSE)

              Package     Version
                abind       1.4-5
              acepack       1.4.1
                 ade4      1.7-10
            albersusa       0.3.0
        AnnotationDbi      1.40.0
          ansistrings       1.0.0
                  ape         5.0
                  aqp        1.15
                  ash      1.0-15
           assertthat       0.2.0
                astsa         1.8
                ATmet         1.2
              automap      1.0-14
            backports       1.1.2
               base64         2.0
            base64enc       0.1-3
                bazar       1.0.6
               BBmisc        1.11
             beeswarm       0.2.3
                   BH    1.66.0-1
```

I thought I could load all the packages then run `devtools::session_info()` to find what I want
https://www.r-bloggers.com/loading-all-installed-r-packages/

```
lapply(.packages(all.available=TRUE), 
        function(x) library(x, character.only=TRUE))
```

But then I ran into another problem: loading too many packages at the same time `maximal number of DLLs reached...`. Package `changepoint` is only the 53th package out of 100+ packages

```
 Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘changepoint’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'C:/RCat/library/changepoint/libs/x64/changepoint.dll':
  `maximal number of DLLs reached...
```

**Edit 1**: I used the code suggested by @Dason but had these errors

```
# empty folder
> sapply(dir(.libPaths()), isGithub)
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
In addition: Warning message:
In packageDescription(pkg) :
  DESCRIPTION file of package 'file31043e741b3f' is missing or broken

# only lattice.dll left in lattice/lib/x64  
> sapply(dir(.libPaths()), isGithub)
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
In addition: Warning message:
In packageDescription(pkg) :
  DESCRIPTION file of package 'lattice' is missing or broken
```

Many thanks for any help!!!

Comment: You can use `packageDescription("package-name")$Repository` to get this information without having to load the package - so perhaps use this as the function in your `lapply`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the source.  If you examine the code for `devtools::session_info()` the relevant info seems to be in `devtools::package_info()`. The code for package_info is:

```
> getAnywhere("package_info")
A single object matching ‘package_info’ was found
It was found in the following places
  namespace:devtools
with value

function (pkgs = loadedNamespaces(), include_base = FALSE, libpath = NULL) 
{
    desc <- suppressWarnings(lapply(pkgs, packageDescription, 
        lib.loc = libpath))
    not_installed <- vapply(desc, identical, logical(1), NA)
    if (any(not_installed)) {
        stop("`pkgs` ", paste0("'", pkgs[not_installed], "'", 
            collapse = ", "), " are not installed", call. = FALSE)
    }
    if (!include_base) {
        base <- vapply(pkgs, pkg_is_base, logical(1))
        pkgs <- pkgs[!base]
    }
    pkgs <- sort_ci(pkgs)
    attached <- pkgs %in% sub("^package:", "", search())
    desc <- lapply(pkgs, packageDescription, lib.loc = libpath)
    version <- vapply(desc, function(x) x$Version, character(1))
    date <- vapply(desc, pkg_date, character(1))
    source <- vapply(desc, pkg_source, character(1))
    pkgs_df <- data.frame(package = pkgs, `*` = ifelse(attached, 
        "*", ""), version = version, date = date, source = source, 
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE, check.names = FALSE)
    rownames(pkgs_df) <- NULL
    class(pkgs_df) <- c("packages_info", "data.frame")
    pkgs_df
}
<bytecode: 0x000000000e211f50>
<environment: namespace:devtools>
```

Basically the output from utils::packageDescription() is getting passed to devtools::pkg_source().  So if you want you could just check what the output of packageDescription looks like and write a function to identify if the description flags it as a github package or not.  I made a first pass at it although I haven't tested extensively.

```
isGithub <- function(pkg){!is.null(packageDescription(pkg)$GithubRepo)}
```

And then to run it on all of our packages we can just list the folders in .libPaths as such

```
sapply(dir(.libPaths()), isGithub)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I had errors using your code. Would you mind checking the updates in my question?

Comment: @IloveCatRPython instead of dir(.libPaths()) use a clean vector of package names that you want to check. That was my quick and dirty way to get that but you can clean it up a bit. installed.packages() is probably a better way to do that part.

Comment: Thank you again! That is very helpful suggestion. I post an answer that works for me

Comment: i think this only works if the package has a URL tag in the DESCRIPTIONS file

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to @Dason, I finally got this to work

Function to find packages installed from GitHub

```
isGithub <- function(pkg){
    !is.null(packageDescription(pkg)$GithubRepo)
}
```

Get all packages in my local library

```
my_lib <- as.data.frame(library()$result, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Check which packages are from GitHub

```
result <- sapply(my_lib$Package, isGithub)
df <- data.frame(package = names(result), github_or_not = result, 
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
head(df[df$result == TRUE, ])

     names.result. result
4           bindr   TRUE
5        bindrcpp   TRUE
6        blogdown   TRUE
9          chroma   TRUE
17          dplyr   TRUE
21          editR   TRUE
```

Comment: Would like to test this solution. What is `df` here? Can you update to make it fully reproducible?

Comment: Write `library()$results` (note the "s") to avoid a partial-name matching warning.

Comment: ...and the last line should simply be `head(df[result, ])` (or `head(df[df$github_or_not, ])`)-

Answer (score 2):

A little modification that allows you to go through your libraries and determine the source of each including the name of the github repo

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'ggplot2':
#>   method         from 
#>   [.quosures     rlang
#>   c.quosures     rlang
#>   print.quosures rlang
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'rvest':
#>   method            from
#>   read_xml.response xml2
allmypackages <- as.data.frame(installed.packages())
allmypackages <- allmypackages %>%
  filter(Priority != "base" | is.na(Priority)) %>%
  select(-c(Enhances:MD5sum, LinkingTo:Suggests)) %>%
  droplevels()

package_source <- function(pkg){
  x <- as.character(packageDescription(pkg)$Repository)
  if (length(x)==0) {
    y <- as.character(packageDescription(pkg)$GithubRepo)
    z <- as.character(packageDescription(pkg)$GithubUsername)
    if (length(y)==0) {
      return("Other")
    } else {
      return(str_c("GitHub repo = ", z, "/", y))
    }
  } else {
    return(x)
  }
}

head(sapply(allmypackages$Package, package_source),60)
#>  [1] "CRAN"                            "CRAN"                           
#>  [3] "CRAN"                            "CRAN"                           
#>  [5] "CRAN"                            "CRAN"                           
#>  [7] "CRAN"                            "CRAN"                           
#>  [9] "CRAN"                            "CRAN"                           
#> [11] "CRAN"                            "CRAN"                           
#> [13] "CRAN"                            "CRAN"                           
#> [15] "CRAN"                            "CRAN"                           
#> [17] "CRAN"                            "CRAN"                           
#> [19] "CRAN"                            "CRAN"                           
#> [21] "CRAN"                            "CRAN"                           
#> [23] "CRAN"                            "CRAN"                           
#> [25] "CRAN"                            "CRAN"                           
#> [27] "CRAN"                            "CRAN"                           
#> [29] "CRAN"                            "CRAN"                           
#> [31] "CRAN"                            "CRAN"                           
#> [33] "CRAN"                            "CRAN"                           
#> [35] "CRAN"                            "CRAN"                           
#> [37] "CRAN"                            "CRAN"                           
#> [39] "CRAN"                            "CRAN"                           
#> [41] "CRAN"                            "CRAN"                           
#> [43] "CRAN"                            "CRAN"                           
#> [45] "Other"                           "R-Forge"                        
#> [47] "CRAN"                            "CRAN"                           
#> [49] "CRAN"                            "CRAN"                           
#> [51] "CRAN"                            "CRAN"                           
#> [53] "CRAN"                            "CRAN"                           
#> [55] "CRAN"                            "CRAN"                           
#> [57] "CRAN"                            "CRAN"                           
#> [59] "GitHub repo = cjtexas/colourgen" "CRAN"
allmypackages$whereat <- sapply(allmypackages$Package, package_source)
```

<sup>Created on 2019-05-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

`pak::lib_status()` gets a tibble with package info. The repository column contains `CRAN` for packages downloaded from CRAN. Read the function [reference guide](https://pak.r-lib.org/reference/lib_status.html).

```r
pak::lib_status()
#> # A data frame: 31 × 31                                                 
#>    library   package version prior…¹ title license sugge…² built depends
#>    <chr>     <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr>  
#>  1 /Library… base    4.2.2   base    "The… Part o… methods R 4.… NA     
#>  2 /Library… boot    1.3-28  recomm… "Boo… Unlimi… MASS, … R 4.… R (>= …
#>  3 /Library… class   7.3-20  recomm… "Fun… GPL-2 … NA      R 4.… R (>= …
#>  4 /Library… cluster 2.1.4   recomm… "\"F… GPL (>… MASS, … R 4.… R (>= …
#>  5 /Library… codeto… 0.2-18  recomm… "Cod… GPL     NA      R 4.… R (>= …
#>  6 /Library… compil… 4.2.2   base    "The… Part o… NA      R 4.… NA     
#>  7 /Library… datase… 4.2.2   base    "The… Part o… NA      R 4.… NA     
#>  8 /Library… filelo… 1.0.2   NA      "Por… MIT + … callr … R 4.… NA     
#>  9 /Library… foreign 0.8-83  recomm… "Rea… GPL (>… NA      R 4.… R (>= …
#> 10 /Library… graphi… 4.2.2   base    "The… Part o… NA      R 4.… NA     
#> # … with 21 more rows, 22 more variables: needscompilation <lgl>,       
#> #   repository <chr>, imports <chr>, remotetype <chr>,                  
#> #   remotepkgref <chr>, remoteref <chr>, remoterepos <chr>,             
#> #   remotepkgplatform <chr>, remotesha <chr>, enhances <chr>,           
#> #   linkingto <chr>, md5sum <chr>, platform <chr>, biocviews <chr>,     
#> #   sysreqs <chr>, ref <chr>, type <chr>, status <chr>, rversion <chr>, 
#> #   sources <list>, repotype <chr>, deps <list>, and abbreviated …
```