# Determine source of R package

Tags: r

Does R store the location a package was installed from, and is it possible to access this?

How would you be able to tell, given that the package version numbers are the same, if a package was installed from CRAN, or a specific GitHub repository? I am aware that `packageVersion()` will give the version number, but this gives no information on the source of the package.

Another motivational aspect to this question is for packages installed from GitHub, how would you determine which repository (or fork) a package was installed from? This aspect of my question is not answered in the [suggested duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49698348/how-to-find-out-which-package-was-installed-from-github-in-my-r-library).

Comment: You might look into how {renv} builds its lockfile as that contains package source information

Comment: Maybe `packageDescription(..., field = "Repository")` ? It returns `"CRAN"` for CRAN packages and `NA` for packages I build myself or that are not installed. I haven't tried with a package from github but also expect an `NA` return value.

Comment: Also check out available.packages() in base.

Comment: Maybe `fields <- c("Package", "Version", "URL");installed.packages()[, fields]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find out which package was installed from GitHub in my R library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49698348/how-to-find-out-which-package-was-installed-from-github-in-my-r-library)

Comment: @Roland, that does indeed return `NA` for packages installed from GitHub. So while it does tell me if a package is from CRAN, it wouldn't answer which repository or fork it was from.

Comment: I'm not sure github is an actual package repository as R understands the term.

Comment: The provenance of a package is not tracked carefully. R was basically built around the idea of a central package repository (CRAN). github didn't exist for much of the language's lifetime. There is no mechanism for tracking fork/repo metadata in R itself. The `remotes::install_github` function does all the GithubRepo metadata but that's not a core R flag. It would be expected that source information could be inferred from the package version number or documentation.